# How to select element inside template tag?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<template id="temp">
    <input class="abc">
</template>

document.getElementById('temp').querySelector('.abc').value='123'

//Cannot set value of undefined
```

If I try to log the element, it also says undefined. How do I select the `input` inside the `template`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the template content first using `.content`, then select the element.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("temp").content.querySelector('.abc');
input.value='123';

//equivalent to document.getElementById('temp').content.querySelector('.abc').value='123'


console.log(input.value);
```

```html
<template id="temp">
    <input class="abc">
</template>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's relatively easy to do that. What you're missing is `content`.

```
document.getElementById('temp').content.querySelector('.abc').value='123'
```